# ActiveRecord - Can't use column names in BETWEEN statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have a Users table, a Purchases table, and a Premiums table, which a User is added to if they're signed up for a Premium service. The Premium table has the User id, the date they were added, and the date they were removed. I'd like to find purchases that were made while a User was part of the Premium service. I was thinking something like:

`Purchase.joins(user: :premiums).where("purchases.date BETWEEN ? AND ?", "premiums.add_date", "premiums.remove_date")`

When I try variations of this, I receive the following error:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "premiums.add_date"`

If I split it into two `.where` statements it works fine:

`Purchase.joins(user: :premiums).where("purchases.date >= premiums.add_date").where("purchases.date <= premiums.remove_date")`

What is it about the BETWEEN statement that prevents me from using typical column names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Postgres is attempting to sanitize/quote the bound values but really you're referencing existing columns in another table. Using `?` placeholder syntax is for literals, not references to existing columns.

What happens when you inline the named columns (hence not bind values) that you insert into the query placeholders of `?`.

So instead of:

```
Purchase.joins(user: :premiums)
.where("purchases.date BETWEEN ? AND ?", "premiums.add_date", "premiums.remove_date")
```

Try

```
Purchase.joins(user: :premiums)
 .where("purchases.date BETWEEN premiums.add_date AND premiums.remove_date")
```

You were already doing this in your version that uses two `where` clauses.